# UWP C# PivotItem don't recognize namespace

Tags: c#, uwp

I used in the past pivot to go through pages in my tabs. it was working OK. Now when I'm trying to add new page to pivot, it is not recognized by PivotItem. No matter what I do, rebuild, restart. The new page is same like all other, and should  be no difference in referencing.

[image]

```
<Page
    xmlns:xml_config="using:Plugin.Maestro_GUI.Xml_config"
    xmlns:stub_perspective ="using:Plugin.Maestro_GUI.Stub_Folder"
    xmlns:tests_folder ="using:Plugin.Maestro_GUI.Tests"

........

<Pivot Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MainPagePivot" Title="" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Background="White">

    <PivotItem>
        <xml_config:Xml_Config_Perspective/>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <stub_perspective:Stub_Perspective/>
    </PivotItem>
    <!--<PivotItem>
        <tests_folder:Run_Tests /> THIS IS NOT RECOGNIZABLE
    </PivotItem>-->
```

[image]

Comment: could you share a mini sample that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: can you explain what do u mean by mini sample? by the way, I asked people around me, as my understanding it's was also a bug in wpf, but rebuilding project was suppose to solve it.

Comment: I mean I could not reproduce your issue, please provide [mcve].